# Entering the EU on a Temporary Canadian Passport

Tags: passport-renewals

My passport expires the end of January 2018, and I was turned away from my flight yesterday for less than 90 days on my passport.

Has anyone entered the EU on a temporary passport?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume that at some point in time someone entered the EU with some sort of temporary passport. What question are you actually trying to answer?

Comment: You'd probably be better to use the Urgent or Express processing to get a new passport quickly. The fees are $110 / $50 on top of the renewal fee of $120. https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/fees/passport-canada.html